# SoapUI (Ready! API) uses same HTTP Authorization for Proxy

Tags: soapui

When setting the Proxy settings manually in SoapUI (Ready! API) from Smartbear, it uses the same settings than for the HTTP Authorization to the server, leading to 407 - Auth required from the Proxy server.

The same test using curl works perfectly: it takes the Proxy username / password for the `Proxy-Authorization` header and the params in `--user` for the `Authorization` header.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug in both SoapUI and Ready! API. A workaround exists however.

Set up the proxy normally with credentials.
Skip setting the credentials on the request. 
Instead open the header tab and add a new header called `Authorization`.
Take the username and password in the form `username:password` and [base64 encode](https://www.base64encode.org/) it. Set the value of the header to `Basic base64string`. Example: If the username was user and password was pass the value should be `Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz`.

This will make the request get correct `Proxy-Authorization` and `Authorization` headers.

Comment: Do you have the link to the referred bug?

Comment: Is this still a relevant bug? I am trying this in SoapUI 5.2.1

Comment: Yes indeed it is. Thanks for posting this answer! @joel-jonsson

Comment: And it is still a bug in 5.3.0 as well. It seems it was there even in 4.0.1 as per https://it-obey.com/index.php/ssl-webservices-proxy-auth-soapui/

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make it work with HTTPS using @joel-jonsson workaround in SOAP UI 5.3.0 and used another workaround with a local proxy (Fiddler) to add the Authorization header as per it-obey.com/index.php/ssl-webservices-proxy-auth-soapui